# comparar 2 objetos de la misma clase java

Tags: java

no se como comparar 2 objetos de la misma clase y comparar cual es mayor.

La parte que no entiendo como hacerla esta en negrita, no entiendo como comparar las colas ya que van hacer creadas en otro archivo para probarlas.
Me pueden ayudar?

Los datos que guarda un objeto de tipo MarketQueue son el numero de cola (correlativo, conforme se van creando colas), y la capacidad maxima que tiene la cola (numero maximo de personas en la cola). Estos datos no pueden ser accedidos desde afuera de la clase, a menos de que sea por medio de los metodos int getQueueNumber() y int getCapacity() que devuelven el numero de cola y la capacidad, respectivamente.

La clase tiene un solo constructor que recibe de parametro la capacidad de la cola.

La clase debe llevar un conteo del numero de colas creadas (privado), y debe poder devolver este numero por medio de el metodo int getNumberOfQueues()

**La clase debe guardar la cola creada (un objeto MarketQueue) que tenga la mayor capacidad (privado), y ser capaz de devolver esta cola por medio del metodo MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue()**

Debe tener un metodo toString() en donde se muestre el numero de cola y su capacidad.

Mi codigo en Java es:

```
public class MarketQueue{

    private static int conteoDeColas = 0;
    int correlativo;
    int capacidad;

    //constructor
    public MarketQueue(int capacidad){
        int correlativo;
        int capacidad;
        conteoDeColas++;
    }

    //metodos
    public int getQueueNumber(){
        return correlativo;
    }

    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacidad;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfQueues(){
        return conteoDeColas;
    }

// Este metodo no se como hacerlo //

    public static MarketQueue getMaxCapacityQueue(){

        return ;
    }

    public String toString(){

    } 

}
```

**He probado cosas como:**

```
if(MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacity()) >= MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacity()) {
            return MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacity()) = MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacity());
        } else {
            return MarketQueue.getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacity());
    }
```

**pero no funciona**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos por parte...

Primero en tu codigo tu **constructor** no hace absolutamente nada... Deberias intentar cambiarlo por algo como esto:

```
//constructor
public MarketQueue(int capacidad){
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
    this.conteoDeColas++;
}
```

Teniendo eso en cuenta entonces procedemos al otro paso que es guardar la cola que mayor capacidad tenga... Para hacer esto basta con declarar un **objeto** de tipo **MarketQueue** dentro de la propia clase y hacerlo **estatico** y modificarlo segun cambie la mayor cola. Por tanto:

```
public class MarketQueue{

    private static MarketQueue maxQueueCapacity = new MarketQueue(0);
    private static int conteoDeColas = 0;
    int correlativo;
    int capacidad;

    //constructor
    public MarketQueue(int capacidad){
        this.capacidad = capacidad;     
        this.conteoDeColas++;
    }

    //metodos
    public int getQueueNumber(){
        return correlativo;
    }

    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacidad;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfQueues(){
        return conteoDeColas;
    }
 }
```

Y por ultimo debes pensar que necesitas para ***comparar*** las **colas** a medidas que se crean.. Pos sencillo si siempre llamamos al **constructor** al crear una clase pues ahí hacemos la comparación y actualizamos tu **clase** entera y quedaría así:

```
public class MarketQueue{

    private static MarketQueue maxQueueCapacity = new MarketQueue(0);
    private static int conteoDeColas = 0;
    private int correlativo;
    private int capacidad;

    //constructor
    public MarketQueue(int capacidad){
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        if(this.conteoDeColas > 0 && maxQueueCapacity.getCapacity() < capacidad)
            maxQueueCapacity.setCapacidad(capacidad);
        conteoDeColas++;
    }

    //metodos
    public int getQueueNumber(){
        return correlativo;
    }

    private void setCapacidad(int capacidad)
    {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
    }

    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacidad;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfQueues(){
        return conteoDeColas;
    }
    public static MarketQueue getMaxCapacityQueue(){
        return maxQueueCapacity;
    }
}
```

> Para obtener la **capacidad maxima** de más está decir que simplemente llamando al metodo **getMaxCapacityQueue().getCapacidad()** lo obtienes